# How to call jquery function in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mediaelement.js

I am using jQuery Mobile + MediaElement.JS (MP3 jQuery Plugin)

The MP3 player is working fine. But the page won't navigate to other pages when I click the menu links. I can see only the loading icon.

```
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();
```

Above is the function to call the MP3 player. i placed it in just above the `</body>`. When I remove the above script, i can navigate to other page but the MP3 player doesn't work.

This is the error I'm getting:

> TypeError: $ is not a function $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();

When I place `jquery.js` in the head, before any libraries, I get this:

[image: error message]

Finally, if I change the call to the player to `jQuery('video,audio').mediaelementplayer()` I get this:

[image: error message]

Comment: Is there any javascript error that may break other code?

Comment: Sounds like `mediaelementplayer();` is blocking jQuery Mobile's events in some way. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @Omar Yes. I placed like that only.

Comment: we cant keep on guessing, add more details.

Comment: We can't keep guessing. Post more code.

Answer (score 2):

I have used successfully jqm (single page app) with mediaelement.js in the past. The way i had used it was by calling

```
var mediaPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer(videoSelector);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Please have a look at a working example it may help you,

http://jsfiddle.net/JXdNd/
*(the video will not play due to cdn cross domain issues, but it should work nicely within your own domain)*

**HTML**

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>home</h1>

    </div> <a href="#page1" data-role="button">page1</a>

</div>
<div id="page1" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>page1</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <video width="200px" height="200px" id="video-player" class="video-player" controls="control" preload="none"><source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bzu2pcyvE0"></video>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p style='width:200px'>Think Geek</p> 
            <a href="#page2" data-role="button">page2</a>
 <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="back">back</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>page2</h1>
 <a href="#page1" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="back">back</a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
/*$(document).ready(function(){*/
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e, data) {
    var videoSelector = '#'+$(e.target).attr("id")+' .video-player';
    if ($(videoSelector).length>0) {
        var mediaPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer(videoSelector);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
});
```